# pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++

```
//if the following code works  
char *ptr=a+12;  
//why doesnt this work  
char *(ptr=a+12);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `(ptr=a+12)` is not a valid name for a variable. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 2):

because `char *ptr=a+12;` is a declaration with an initializer and `char *(ptr=a+12);` is ... well, nothing.

But this will work.

```
char* ptr;
ptr = a+12;
char x = *(ptr = a+12);
```

Answer (score 0):

`char * ptr;` declares a variable, `=a+12` gives it a value. What you're doing makes no sense, the variable must exist in order for a value to be assigned. What are you trying to achieve?

This would be valid.

```
char * foo;
char * ptr = (foo = a + 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring as a pointer a whole expression, which makes no sense. A pointer must be a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`()` has a higher priority. So, the expression in it evaluates first and is not a valid `lvalue` to assign to.

Answer (score 0):

`char* ptr = a + 12;` declares and defines a pointer-to-char to point 12 characters after `a` does.

`char* (ptr = a + 12);` tries to assign the value (`a + 12`) to the pointer `ptr`, and then dereference it to produce a value. However `Type value` is not valid syntax (like `int 0;` or `char 'x';` are not valid), and `ptr` is never declared/defined.

In short, it's completely senseless.